# Upload a file in azure

Tags: python, django, azure, ftp

I want to upload images in Microsoft azure through a python script and show those images in a dashboard build on django admin interface. Now, i figured since i am sending pics i should be using ftp.. So this is the code:

```
import ftplib
session = ftplib.FTP('server.address.com','USERNAME','PASSWORD')
file = open('kitten.jpg','rb')                  # file to send
session.storbinary('STOR kitten.jpg', file)     # send the file
file.close()                                    # close file and FTP
session.quit()
```

Now, i don't know how to setup ftp server in azure and how would i be able to fetch those images from server to my dashboard.. I don't know much about deployment so any link to do this or guide would be welcome/helpful.

Comment: FTP is an ancient totally insecure technology that should have been killed off 20 years ago.

Comment: but what has this got to do with django?

Comment: Does this have anything related to Python? As far as I understand, the question is _how to setup a FTP server in Azure_...

Comment: This question is super-broad and off-topic: *Lots* of ways to upload content, ftp being one of them (though it would require you to host an ftp server). I suggest spending a bit of time on the Azure site looking at the different storage services and related python SDKs to see what your options are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you tried to create a Django app to upload & show images via FTP on Azure WebApps.

Per my experience, the only feasible way on Azure WebApps is that reading or writing images via Kudu FTP, please refer to the offical wiki [page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-files-via-ftp) for Kudu FTP, and set up the user name & password via Azure portal.

However, I think it's not a best practice for image showing on Azure WebApp, because normally there is concurrency limits for uploading & downloading in FTP that be not suitable for your scenario, and the storage via FTP on Azure WebApp is ready for App self, not for resource.

So my suggestion is that using Azure Blob Storage to read & write images, and Django Framework has supported for integrating with Azure Storgae via simply setup configuration. Please refer to the Django document [reference](http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/azure.html) for Azure Storage to knwo how to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I was novice back then in this  and I did a lot of research work.. I am currently using Azure Blob storage.. Thanks for your help..